# Excel Countif range contains X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to create a formula, that counts the cells containing a "x".

This is my current try, but even though the range contains one "x" it doesn't count it.

```
=COUNTIF(F12:T12;ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x";F12)))
```

A visual help:

[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIF(F12:T12; "x")` or `=COUNTIF(F12:T12; "*x*")`

Comment: thx. Easier then thought 

Answer (score 0):

Easier than thought. Thx to Jeeped.

```
=COUNTIF(F12:T12; "x")
```